# PHP Drop Down Data from Database

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make an `select field` for data according to my database.  So, basically, I want it to have a dropdown menu for all the users in my database.  So like instead of doing:

```
<select>
  <option>1st User in Db</option>
  <option>2nd User in Db</option>
</select>
```

It just automatically shows all.

I tried fetching a $row['uname'], and setting it as $user, but then it only shows MY user in the dropdown.

Example:  http://prntscr.com/dwksy

It only shows my account, admin, instead of all the other ones.  Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the SQL you're using to query the database? And the PHP generating the list?

Comment: Sounds like you need a different query to get the right info back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'config.php';
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$qry=("SELECT `rank`, `uname` FROM users WHERE uname='$user'");
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row["rank"]

if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    if ($rank >= 3) {
        $qry=("SELECT `rank`, `uname` FROM users");
        $result=mysql_query($qry);

        echo "
        <form action='' method='POST'>
        <select>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $rank = $row['rank'];
            $users = $row['uname'];
            $lol = ucwords($users);

            echo "<option>$lol</option>";
        }

        echo "</select>
        </form>
        ";
      } else {
          echo "Your level is not 3, but you are logged in.";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Please login.";
  }
```

Comment: Okay, now it is getting tangled with my if statements

Comment: Do you want to add them to the question?

Comment: Added !! :)  This has to be atleast 15 chars so iosfjeorjferf

Comment: I think that should do it. There are a few things you should look at, though, like making sure your query is returning data; and you might want to look into converting it to use PDO, too.

Comment: That's the code that doesn't work and only shows MY user.  I want it to show every user in the database.  Can you fix up my code?  When I add the wait loop, it just gives me unexpected T_ELSE, because it gets tangled with my other codes.

Comment: I've done as alexis pointed out and removed the WHERE - it should list every user in the table now. WHat line is it giving you the Unexpected T_ELSE error on?

Comment: Ugh, on your edit, now it gives me the second to last error, "Your level is not 3, but you are logged in."  :(  Help

Comment: Darn; yes. That's because you're checking their level, but that's pulled from the database; so you're comparing their level against an unknown. You might have to add their level to $_SESSION, as you do their username, when they log in - otherwise, it gets a little complex.

Comment: This discussion will be long and I don't have enough rep to chat.  Go to my chat xat.com/cpRichNich, I'm ryan.

Comment: Alas, I've not got the time for that - I need to head out imminently. Basically, you're using your SQL query at the moment both to list users, and to check the current user's login level. You can do either one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Comment: I did this sort of thing with a PHP table of all users, but it still remains the session.  I am trying to do the same thing.  I don't know why this one wont wokr.

Comment: @user1604290 Have a look at the latest version.

Comment: Phew; and still two minutes before hometime!

Answer (score 1):

Your query only fetches the user recorded in `$_SESSION`. Drop the WHERE clause to get all users in the result, then read them with @andrewsi's loop and spit out one `<option>` for each user returned:

```
$qry=("SELECT `rank`, `uname` FROM users");
```